# JavaFX How to throws exception message to label?

Tags: java, validation, javafx, scenebuilder

I write warehouse application and firstly I wrote code which will be displayed in console. Now i want to display it as window in javafx. How I can throw it to javaFX label? Below is code which i have as validators and now i want to throw it in javafx. I have also implement user service which send login and password and check it by validators. Im working in scenebuilder. Maybe anyone has easier solution for check login, password and throw information about wrong length?

Validator

```
public class UserValidator {

private UserDao userDao = UserDaoImpl.getInstance();

private static UserValidator instance = null;

public static UserValidator getInstance() {
    if(instance == null) {
        instance = new UserValidator();
    }
    return instance;
}

private final int LOGIN_MIN_LENGTH = 5;
private final int LOGIN_MAX_LENGTH = 20;
private final int PASSWORD_MIN_LENGTH = 8;
private final int PASSWORD_MAX_LENGTH = 20;

public boolean isValidateAddUser(User user) throws UserLoginIsExistException, UserLoginEnoughLengthException, UserPasswordEnoughLengthException,
        UserPasswordIsOneCharUpCaseException {
    if(isLoginEnoughLength(user.getLogin()))
        throw new UserLoginEnoughLengthException("Login must be minimum 5 and maximum 20 letters!");

        if(isPasswordEnoughLength(user.getPassword()))
            throw new UserPasswordEnoughLengthException("Password must be minimum 8 and maximum 20 letters!");

        if(isPasswordOneCharUpperCase(user.getPassword()))
            throw new UserPasswordIsOneCharUpCaseException("Password must have one uppercase letter!");

        if (isUserAlreadyExist(user.getLogin()))
            throw new UserLoginIsExistException("Login is exist!");

    return true;
}

public boolean isValidateUpdateUserPassword(String newPassword) throws UserPasswordEnoughLengthException,
        UserPasswordIsOneCharUpCaseException{

    if(isPasswordEnoughLength(newPassword)) {
        throw new UserPasswordEnoughLengthException("Password must be minimum 8 and maximum 20 letters!");
    }

    if(isPasswordOneCharUpperCase(newPassword)) {
        throw new UserPasswordIsOneCharUpCaseException("Password must have one uppercase letter!");
    }
    return true;
}

private boolean isLoginEnoughLength(String login) {
    return login.length() < LOGIN_MIN_LENGTH || login.length() > LOGIN_MAX_LENGTH;
}

private boolean isPasswordEnoughLength(String password) {
    return password.length() < PASSWORD_MIN_LENGTH || password.length() > PASSWORD_MAX_LENGTH;
}

private boolean isPasswordOneCharUpperCase(String password) {
    for(char checkUpperCase : password.toCharArray()) {
        if(Character.isUpperCase(checkUpperCase)) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

private boolean isUserAlreadyExist(String login) {
    List<User> users = null;
    users = userDao.getAllUsers();
    for(User user : users) {
        if(user.getLogin().equals(login)) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

}

UI

```
public class UserImpl implements UserService {

private UserValidator userValidator = UserValidator.getInstance();
private UserDao userDao = UserDaoImpl.getInstance();

private static UserImpl instance = null;

public static UserImpl getInstance() {
    if (instance == null) {
        instance = new UserImpl();
    }
    return instance;
}

public boolean addUser(User user) {
    try {
        if (userValidator.isValidateAddUser(user)) {
            userDao.addUser(user);
            return true;
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
    return false;
}
```

UI facade

```
public class UserFacadeImpl implements UserFacade {
private static UserService userService = UserImpl.getInstance();
private static UserFacadeImpl instance = null;

public static UserFacadeImpl getInstance() {
    if(instance == null) {
        instance = new UserFacadeImpl();
    }
    return instance;
}

public boolean registerUser(User user) {
    return userService.addUser(user);
}
```

Register Controller

```
public class RegisterControler {
String login, password, email;
private static UserFacade userFacade = UserFacadeImpl.getInstance();

@FXML
TextField fieldLogin;
@FXML
TextField fieldPassword;
@FXML
TextField fieldEmail;
@FXML
Label labelValidator;

public boolean isRegister()  {
    login = fieldLogin.getText();
    password = fieldPassword.getText();
    email = fieldEmail.getText();
    User user = new User(login, password, email);

    if (userFacade.registerUser(user)) {
            labelValidator.setText("Register Successfully!");
        }
    else {

    }

    return false;
    }


public void buttonRegister() {
    isRegister();
}
```

Comment: Don't squash the exception in `UserImpl` and `UserFacadeImpl`, but either propagate it back to the UI, or at least return a value that indicates what failed. Your `isValidateAddUser` only ever returns `true`, or throws an exception, so the return value is pretty much useless. Why not return, e.g. an `enum` that represents the actual thing that happened, instead of throwing exceptions from that method?

Comment: Ok, so how i understood it. Good solution is to remove try/catch blocks and write exceptions as normal message in enum and there compare it with method which will check validate?

Comment: Yes, something like that. The general rule is that you should use exceptions for exceptional conditions, and not for processing the normal logical flow of your application. These are borderline cases, and depend a bit on the rest of your app; e.g. if you check the length of the password before letting the user submit it, then the password not being long enough would be an "exceptional condition"; but if not, then it's logical flow.

Comment: Still i dont know how to resolve it by enums. Can you give me example for it?